# How do you define a function of a class in another Javascript file using Node require?

Tags: javascript, node.js

Let's say I have a class `A` defined in its own JavaScript file, like this:

A.js

```
class A {
    constructor() {
        // blah blah blah
    }
    func() {
        // a long function
    }
}
```

If I have a function (e.g. `func()`) that I want to be contained in its own file (for organizational purposes), how would I accomplish this?

What I want is something like this:

A.js

```
class A {
    constructor() {
        this.func = {};
    }
} exports.A = A;
```

ADefinition.js

```
var A = require('./A.js');
A.func = () => {
    // a long function
}
```

This obviously doesn't work, but how  would one accomplish this?

Comment: Just add the function to the prototype.

Comment: just to make sure I understand this, would I do A.prototype.func = () => {}?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Classes are mostly just syntax sugar. In ES5, you define prototype functions by assigning to the prototype:

```
function A() {
}
A.prototype.func = function() {
}
```

Classes can work the same way:

```
var A = require('./A.js');
A.prototype.func = () => {
    // a long function
}
```

Though, note that if you use an arrow function, you won't have access to the instance - you may well need a full-fledged function instead:

```
A.prototype.func = function() {
    // a long function
};
```

Also, personally, I think I'd prefer to put `func` on the class *next to the class definition* for code clarity, rather than running a module that performs side effects (like your current code is attempting to do), for example:

```
const func = require('./func.js');
class A {
  constructor() {
  }
}
A.prototype.func = func;
```

Comment: Doing this gives me the following error message:
TypeError: Cannot read property 'prototype' of undefined

Comment: Works fine for me: https://codesandbox.io/s/k55044o5z3 If you're still using your side-effects code, you'll need to assign `A` to the exports themselves, otherwise `A` will just be a *property of the object* you're exporting. eg `module.exports = A` or `const { a } = require('./A.js');`